# Shrink size of UINaviationBar large title text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

Before iOS 11, to make a custom label, I just did this:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 40))
titleLabel.text = self.customTitleText
titleLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
titleLabel.textAlignment = .left
titleLabel.textColor = .white
titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.25
navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

Now, the titleView doesn't seem to affect the large title. What can I do to achieve a text shrink in iOS 11?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082928/3984542

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    ]
```

Comment: Which size? Can you explain more?

Comment: The font size (i.e. calculate the correct font size for the width of the screen)